# Is it possible to run a cron job in Vespa?

Tags: vespa

In my application I have to send data at particular interval of time from  vespa.How should I achieve it? Is there any cron job or scheduler service to achieve this?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in scheduler but you are probably already familiar with developing container applications so you can run your own scheduler and export documents, or perform queries?

Comment: Do I have to create external schedular to perform queries with vespa?

Comment: You could obviously schedule query execution from within a container plugin but you don't mention what you want to do with the data returned, if you gonna consume that data outside of Vespa it does not make much sense to schedule inside a Vespa plugin.

Comment: Actually I need to send push notification through vespa at particular interval of time. Notification will have data fetched from vespa. So How can I acieve that?I want vespa automatically fetched data from itself and send it using any notifiaction service at particulat interval of time.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your use case. You can write a vespa container plugin https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/jdisc/container-components.html which schedules a task which fetches data from vespa by using the programatic query api and which integrates with other services.

Comment: In my case, there is FCM notification service,vespa and a mobile app and all my data is in vespa. I want to trigerred notifaction from vespa with at some point of time like 12:00am, 7:00pm etc and its fetches data from itself and send to FCM Then the FCM will send notifications to registered mobile devices.I want vespa does it automatically.Thats my case.

Comment: That sounds like a container plugin with a simple java scheduled task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181587/discussion-between-mohammad-sunny-and-jo-kristian-bergum).